# How to Enable Edit option in this javascript program

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a JavaScript program to add records from a Form to Table i created `AddRow()`,`reset()`,`DeleteRow()` functions in this program but I am unable to create the `EditRow()`function in this program.

```js
function addRow() {
  var id = document.getElementById("empId");
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
  var address = document.getElementById("address");
  var email = document.getElementById("mail");
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = empId.value;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = name.value;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = gender.value;
  row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = address.value;
  row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = mail.value;
  row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
  row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Edit" onClick="Javacsript:EditRow(this)">';
  empId.value = "";
  name.value = "";
  gender.value = "";
  address.value = "";
  mail.value = "";
}

function EditRow(obj) {
  alert('How to implement this ?');
}

function reset() {
  var id = document.getElementById("empId");
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
  var address = document.getElementById("address");
  var email = document.getElementById("mail");
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
  empId.value = "";
  name.value = "";
  gender.value = "";
  address.value = "";
  mail.value = "";
}


function deleteRow(obj) {
  var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
  table.deleteRow(index);
}
```

```html
<div id="myform">
  <b>Employee Information</b>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ID:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="empId">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="name">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" id="gender" value="male" />Male
          <br>
          <input type="radio" id="gender" value="Female" />FeMale
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="textarea" id="address">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" id="mail" name="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      &nbsp;
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="javascript:addRow()">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="update" value="Update" onClick="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="mydata">
  <table id="myTableData" border="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td><b>ID</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Name</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Gender</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Address</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Email</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Action</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Surendran, welcome to SO. ***Why*** unable? Don't let anyone believe its for laziness. read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this...
I used input type hidden to update data and edit and update function .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML dynamic table using JavaScript</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myform">
<b>Employee Information</b>
<form method="post" action=""> 
<table>

<tr>
<td>ID:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="empId"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender:</td> 
<td> <input type="radio" name="gender"  id="male" value="male" /> Male <br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender"  id="female" value="Female" /> FeMale
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><input type="textarea" id="address"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="email" id="mail" name="Email"></td>
</tr>
&nbsp;

<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="javascript:addRow()"></td>
<td><input type="reset"  value="Reset" /> </td>
<td>
 <input type="hidden" id="updateid" value="">
 <input type="button" id="update" value="Update" onClick="javascript:UpdateRow()">

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="mydata">

<table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>

    <td><b>ID</b></td>
    <td><b>Name</b></td>
    <td><b>Gender</b></td>
    <td><b>Address</b></td>
    <td><b>Email</b></td>
    <td><b>Action</b></td>

</tr>

</table>
</div>

<script>
 function addRow() {
var id= document.getElementById("empId");
var name= document.getElementById("name");
var address= document.getElementById("address");
var email = document.getElementById("mail");
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

if(document.getElementById("male").checked){ 
 var gender="Male";
}else if(document.getElementById('female').checked) {
 var gender="Female";
}

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= empId.value;
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= name.value;
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= gender;
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= address.value;
row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= mail.value;

row.insertCell(5).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
row.insertCell(6).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Edit" onClick="Javacsript:EditRow(this)">';

empId.value="";
name.value="";
gender.value="";
address.value="";
mail.value="";


}
function EditRow(obj){
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
var row = table.rows[index];

var id= document.getElementById("empId");
var name= document.getElementById("name");

if(row.cells[2].innerHTML == "Male"){
 document.getElementById("male").checked = true;
}else{
 document.getElementById("female").checked = true;
}


var address= document.getElementById("address");
var email = document.getElementById("mail");
var updateid= document.getElementById("updateid");

id.value=row.cells[0].innerHTML;
name.value=row.cells[1].innerHTML;
address.value=row.cells[3].innerHTML;
email.value=row.cells[4].innerHTML;
updateid.value=index;
}
function UpdateRow(){

var id= document.getElementById("empId");
var name= document.getElementById("name");
var gender= document.getElementById("gender");
var address= document.getElementById("address");
var email = document.getElementById("mail"); 
var updateid= document.getElementById("updateid");
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

if(document.getElementById("male").checked){
 gender="Male";
}else{
 gender="Female";
}

var row = table.rows[updateid.value];

row.cells[0].innerHTML= id.value;
row.cells[1].innerHTML= name.value;
row.cells[2].innerHTML= gender;
row.cells[3].innerHTML= address.value;
row.cells[4].innerHTML= email.value;

id.value="";
name.value="";
gender.value="";
address.value="";
email.value="";
updateid.value="";
}
function reset(){

var id= document.getElementById("empId");
var name= document.getElementById("name");
var gender= document.getElementById("gender");
var address= document.getElementById("address");
var email = document.getElementById("mail");
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

empId.value="";
name.value="";
gender.value="";
address.value="";
mail.value="";
}


function deleteRow(obj) {

var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
table.deleteRow(index);
  }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mani Thanku for your help every thing will be ok but we can't able to edit the gender in the table so please give me a suggestion for me..

Comment: Use different id names for gender. I modified the code. check once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var txt = null;

function addRow() {
    var id = document.getElementById("empId");
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var address = document.getElementById("address");
    var email = document.getElementById("mail");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = empId.value;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = name.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name="genderS"]:checked').value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = address.value;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = mail.value;
    row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Edit" onClick="Javacsript:EditRow(this)">';

    empId.value = "";
    name.value = "";
    address.value = "";
    mail.value = "";
}

function EditRow(obj) {

    txt = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var tr = document.getElementById("myTableData").getElementsByTagName("tr")
    document.getElementById("empId").value = tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("name").value = tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML).checked = true;
    document.getElementById("address").value = tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("mail").value = tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[4].innerHTML;

}

function updateRow() {
    if (txt != null) {
        var tr = document.getElementById("myTableData").getElementsByTagName("tr");
        tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("empId").value;
        tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
        tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name="genderS"]:checked').value;
        tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("address").value;
        tr[txt].getElementsByTagName("td")[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("mail").value;
        txt = null;
        document.getElementById("reset").click();
    } else {
        console.log("edit row first");
    }
}

function deleteRow(obj) {
    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    table.deleteRow(index);
}
```

```html
<div id="myform">
  <b>Employee Information</b>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ID:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="empId">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="name">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="genderS" id="male" value="male" />Male
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="genderS" id="female" value="female" />FeMale
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="textarea" id="address">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" id="mail" name="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      &nbsp;
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="javascript:addRow()">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="update" value="Update" onClick="javascript:updateRow()">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="mydata">
  <table id="myTableData" border="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td><b>ID</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Name</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Gender</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Address</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Email</b>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2><b>Action</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd consider going about it. Notice you can cut down a bit on typing if you use helper functions and a bit more again if you use loops where possible. I'll also point out that the `form` element has a javascript mehod, `reset` - calling it will reset all controls contained within the form.

Also, rather than setting the text attribute onclick, I've attached handlers to the js event 'click'. This allows us to remove and attach them as we please. In this case, the 'EDIT' button has it's text and function changed after a click, so that it reads 'DONE' and then takes the text from the input elements and re-applies it to the table cells.

The editing function is simply achieved by taking the innerHTML of the first 5 cells in a row, and replacing it with an input whose value is the old innerHTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function addRow() 
{
    var table = byId('myTableData');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = byId('empId').value;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = byId('name').value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = byId('gender').value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = byId('address').value;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = byId('mail').value
    row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="deleteRow(this)"/>';

    var editBtn = newEl('button');
    editBtn.textContent = 'Edit';
    editBtn.addEventListener('click', beginEditRow, false);
    row.insertCell(6).appendChild(editBtn);

    byId('myform').reset();
}

function beginEditRow(evt)
{
    var clickedButton = this;
    var rowElem = clickedButton.parentNode.parentNode;

    var maxCells = 5;
    for (var i=0; i<maxCells; i++)
    {
        var tmpStr = rowElem.cells[i].innerHTML;
        var tmpInput = newEl('input');
        tmpInput.value = tmpStr;
        rowElem.cells[i].innerHTML = '';
        rowElem.cells[i].appendChild(tmpInput);
    }

    this.textContent = "-Done-";
    this.removeEventListener('click', beginEditRow);
    this.addEventListener('click', endEditRow, false);
}

function endEditRow(evt)
{
    var clickedBtn = this;
    var rowElem = clickedBtn.parentNode.parentNode;

    var maxCells = 5;
    for (var i=0; i<maxCells; i++)
    {
        var tmpStr = rowElem.cells[i].childNodes[0].value;
        rowElem.cells[i].innerHTML = tmpStr;
    }
    this.textContent = "Edit";
    this.removeEventListener('click', endEditRow);
    this.addEventListener('click', beginEditRow, false);
}

function deleteRow(obj) 
{
    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = byId("myTableData");
    table.deleteRow(index);
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <b>Employee Information</b>
        <form id="myform" method="post" action="">    
            <table>      
                <tr><th>ID:</th><td><input type="text" id="empId"></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Name:</th><td><input type="text" id="name"></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Gender:</th><td><input type="radio" id="gender" value="male"/>Male<br><input type="radio" id="gender" value="Female" />Female</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Address:</th><td><input type="textarea" id="address"></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Email:</th><td><input type="email" id="mail" name="Email"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="javascript:addRow()"></td><td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td><td><input type="button" id="update" value="Update" onClick=""></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="mydata">
      <table id="myTableData" border="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Address</th><th>Email</th><th>Action</th></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```